# Why shadows behave strangely near corners

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, shadow

i noticed that looking at 2 objects like my finger and a book, when they are very close, it seems like their shadow grows bigger towards eachother ([as in this video](https://youtu.be/BZeLrp_S10Q)). why? is related in some way to quantum mechanics?